# Job Scheduling Prisma

Tags: jobs, job-scheduling, prisma, prisma-graphql

*How to schedule jobs in a NextJS, Prisma, GraphQL-Yoga stack?*

> Think Airbnb-type payouts.

When a guest books host’s property a job is scheduled to issue payout after a certain period of time.

For MeteorJS I used Steve Jobs package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot schedule jobs with Prisma, it is your data layer.

The answer to "How to schedule jobs in a NextJS, GraphQL Yoga stack" is the same as the answer to "How to schedule jobs in a NextJS, Express stack", so it's more a general question than specific to Prisma.

With some quick googling I found this:

https://scotch.io/tutorials/nodejs-cron-jobs-by-examples

Comment: the link is broken

Comment: Seems to be redirected to DO now, https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/nodejs-cron-jobs-by-examples